# Using maven multi module, spring boot and IntelliJ

Tags: eclipse, maven, jsp, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am setting the project with spring boot + maven multi module + Intellij

The structure of project is

```
Parent module
            - src
                - main
                    - java
                    - resources
                    - webapp
            - Web module
                - src
                    - main
                        - java
                        - resources
                        - webapp
                pom.xml(web)
            pom.xml(parent)
```

As you see on the structure the web module is under the parent module,
it has problem when I use on jsp (it's fine with template from spring boot ex thymeleaf).

For example, add jsp at web module src > webapp > WEB-INF (of course I have done with basic setting of spring boot to use jsp) and operate web moudle application
then call from controller. There was no problem at eclipse IDE but Intellij IDE can't find jsp.

For the test result, it post to be find from web moudle but it find from parent module.

So modify Configuration - Enviroment - Working directory to $MODULE_WORKING_DIR$ to fix the problem (web module configuration at boot dashboard)

I want to know exact cause.

Answer (score 0):

You need move WEB-INF to :
resources.META-INF.resources.WEB-INF

of course you need create META-INF and resources (directory) in your resources

Answer (score 0):

If you have **multiple modules**(At intellij), Run> Edit configuration> Select springboot your application > Configuration tab> Working directory -> **$MODULE_WORKING_DIR$**

Also make sure pom.xml

- include tomcat, jasper embeded dependency
- make packaging war

Also, add springboot devtools that will help your jsp page edit without restart.